# What is Boilerplate code, Hot code and Hot spots?

Tags: java, performance, language-agnostic, benchmarking

I know these terms are used in context of performance achievement/optimization.

Recently have been working on that, and have tried searching; but didn't get any example, which clearly elaborate/describe these concepts with the realization of these problems/concepts in real world development scenarios.

Can somebody please thoroughly explain these terms, example scenarios, and where these concepts and terms are likely used.

Thanks.

Comment: A question for the Programmers stack?

Answer (score 15):

"Boilerplate" has nothing to do with performance: it just means standard code that is required to define an application or work with some framework. It's code that is likely to be identical in every application.

A "hot spot", on the other hand, means a part of the code that is executed many times and therefore its performance matters a lot to the overall application performance. Usually a hot spot is identified by actual profiling: it's not a hot spot if it's executed many times but is so trivial that its impact on performance is minimal.

Answer (score 4):

[Boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code)

"hot code" is scalable well written code

"hot spots" are an area of intense activity. They're hot spots because they're frequently executed code.

Answer (score 3):

One definition of "hot spot" is a region of code where the program counter spends a good fraction of its time.
A related term is "bottleneck" which, while ill-defined, generally refers to code localized to a function, routine, or method, that causes a higher fraction of time to be spent than necessary.

Both these terms are very misleading, because there is a huge unwritten assumption.
The assumption is that there are no opportunities to speed up a program that are not a hotspot or a bottleneck.
Speedup opportunities can be more diffuse than that, and if they are not found and fixed, they become the performance limiter.

Let me give an example.
Recently, when working on a C++ program of about 300 lines, I took ten [stackshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), because I wanted to see how I could speed it up.
Four of those stackshots looked like this:

```
CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray,COperation *>::operator[]() line 1555 + 23 bytes
TcProcess() line 246 + 14 bytes ---> COperation* pOp = oplist[i];
CMhAck::Handler() line 165
doit() line 297 + 12 bytes
main() line 318

CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray,CJob *>::operator[]() line 1555 + 23 bytes
SchProcess() line 212 + 14 bytes ---> pJob = joblist[i];
COpAck::Handler() line 145
doit() line 297 + 12 bytes
main() line 318

CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray,CTask *>::operator[]() line 1555 + 23 bytes
TcProcess() line 249 + 18 bytes ---> pTask = pOp->tasks[pOp->iCurTask];
CMhAck::Handler() line 165
doit() line 297 + 12 bytes
main() line 318

CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray,CTask *>::operator[]() line 1555 + 23 bytes
COperation::~COperation() line 57 + 15 bytes ---> CTask* p = tasks[i];
COperation::`scalar deleting destructor'() + 37 bytes
TcProcess() line 259 + 28 bytes
CTskAck::Handler() line 193
doit() line 297 + 12 bytes
main() line 318
```

The program took 20 seconds overall.
What these stack samples are telling me is roughly 40% of that time, or 8 seconds, is spent in the indexing operator on the array class.
That tells me I could reduce running time from 20 seconds to 12 seconds, give or take, if I could do indexing more directly, not through a function call.
The speedup would be 20/12 = 1.67, or about a 67% speedup.
(Notice: I don't give a hoot about "exact" when it comes to timing. What I wanted to do was *find the problem*.)

Now one might easily disagree with that method of fixing the problem, but you can see how I detected *what the problem was*, right?

OK, so where's the "hotspot" and where's the "bottleneck"?
Clearly there's a hotspot in the indexing operator function, but is that where the problem is?
(Actually it's not even that, because it's three different functions.)
Does that mean I should try to make that routine faster?
I don't even own it!

Is there a bottleneck in the form of some "slow routine"?
No!
There's no particular routine that's slow, or a "bad algorithm".

What I did was make a *description* of what it was doing ("It's indexing in certain routines.") where that description applies a large fraction of the time.

The best term I can come up with for these things is "time drain", because it's spending a large fraction of time doing things that don't *really* have to be done.

[More about terminology and popular misconceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679186/most-hazardous-performance-bottleneck-misconceptions/2679514#2679514)

Answer (score 0):

Read Defintion : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code
handle it by https://projectlombok.org/

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you already have sufficient definitions for the term "boilerplate". I would probably wish to back what you have with the help of an example.
Coming from a Java background and recently moving to Scala, you realize that in Java, you can't write statements devoid of semicolons (;). Further, it is not unusual to write thousands of statements for a program that's probably running in production. Your guess is as good as mine, you end up writing a lot of repetitive low-impact code but it happens to be code that's demanded by the Java compiler. Scala is a concise language in the sense that the need to write boilerplate code has been reduced. You don't have to write semi-colons in Scala. Hope this is simplistic enough